# Error: Simple error keeps popping up, unable to progress

Tags: python

So I'm trying to answer a leetcode question but I believe I'm stuck on something simple but I can't figure it out.
The error that keeps popping up is "name 'twoSum' is not defined". Can anyone tell me what I'm missing here? It's clearly defined as far as I can see?

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(num: int, target: int) -> int:
        for i in range(len(num) -1):
            for j in range(i, len(num)-1):
                if num[i] + num[j] == target:
                    list = [i, j]
                    return list
def main():
    num = [3,2,4]
    target = 6
    r= twoSum(num, target)
    print(r)
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to change `twoSum(num, target)` to `Solution.twoSum(num, target)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an object of that class `Solution` first

Change your main to below -

```
def main():
    num = [3,2,4]
    target = 6
    s = Solution()
    r = s.twoSum(num, target)
    print(r)
```

Also I makes me assume that it is one of your first attempts to leetcode. (Apologies if assumption is wrong). This is not how to submit in leetcode.
You just need to fill the function given in the edit. You don't have to call it explicitly. Leetcode will take care of this on it's own.

EDIT - One more (and most important thing)
if you want to call your method in that class `Solution`, you need to add `self` in the method definition like this -

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, num: int, target: int) -> int:
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to call `twoSum()` as `Solution.twoSum()`. That being said; from what you show us it seems useless to be using a `class` at all. Here is my suggestion:

```
def twoSum(num: int, target: int) -> int:
    for i in range(len(num) -1):
        for j in range(i, len(num)-1):
            if num[i] + num[j] == target:
                list = [i, j]
                return list
def main():
    num = [3,2,4]
    target = 6
    r = twoSum(num, target)
    print(r)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```